# How many prototypes for user testing?

Tags: usability-testing, prototype

I was wondering what is the best approach to structuring my prototype? Is it better to have one individual prototype for each scenario/task you are asking the user to complete in testing, so for each task, I give them the prototype that allows them to complete just that task. Thus reducing file size.

Or is it better to create one large prototype that incorporates all the tasks the user will be asked to do?

Comment: Are your scenario/task independent of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all probabilty there will be some parts of the prototype that are needed for more than one task. That is one reason to create one prototype for one test.
Another one: You generally want to see if the application works as a whole, whether users find the necessary functions, information and so on. If you show individual prototypes you might give away the starting point and thus lose information.

A scenario where I would create multiple prototypes: A new feature has to be integrated into something existing and there are multiple ways to do that.

So: in my experience, for one test I generally create one prototype, only in some very special cases multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to use only a single prototype in usability testing. You need to think about the user journey, all the steps and tasks connected in that journey. If it makes sense, great, just use a single prototype to maintain the user experience. But if you need to test two totally different scenarios, it might be more efficient to use different prototypes. Always tell a story to the user, make a presentation to show the situation and make them think separately. The most important thing is the user experience with your product.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).